# Drag and drop from master list to multiple lists

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

**ngx-drag-and-drop-lists** does not have a support area, so I am posting here.

I am having trouble taking the example application code and using it in my app. I can get my items to display in the first list, the source list.  But when I try and drag to one of the group lists, they show the disabled cursor and won't allow me to drop.  The item comes off the source list while I drag, but then reappears when I release the mouse.

```
<div id="patchGroups">
  <!--<div>This is where you manage which servers are in which groups as well as details about the servers.</div>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="unGroupedServers" class="col-md-2 pl-2">
      <div *ngFor="let patchGroup of ungrouped_patchGroups" class="card border-secondary">
        <div class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">{{patchGroup.name}}</div>
        <div class="card-body targets">
          <ul class="list-unstyled"
              [dndList]="{
                disabled: false,
                effectAllowed: 'move',
                allowedTypes: ['server']}"
              [dndModel]="servers">
            <li *ngFor="let server of patchGroup.servers;let i = index"
                [dndDraggable]="{draggable:true, effectAllowed:'move'}"
                (dndMoved)="removeMovedItem(i, servers)"
                style="cursor:pointer;">{{server.name}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="savePatchGroupForm_wrapper" [ngbCollapse]="savePatchGroupForm_isCollapsed">
          <app-add-patch-group-form (toggleCreateGroups)="toggleCreateGroups()"></app-add-patch-group-form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer p-0"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="toggleCreateGroups()" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="Create Group">Create Group</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="groupedServers" class="col-md-10">
      <div *ngIf="grouped_patchGroups.length > 0; else noPatchGroups" class="row flex-row flex-grow flex-nowrap pb-2">
        <div class="col-2" #grouped_patchGroups *ngFor="let patchGroup of grouped_patchGroups">
          <div class="card">
            <!--TODO: make trash can icon display under text and hover over when text is long-->
            <div class="card-header">{{patchGroup.name}} <a (click)="deletePatchGroup([patchGroup.id])" title="Delete group"><fa-icon [icon]="faTrashAlt" class="fa float-right text-secondary"></fa-icon></a></div>
            <div class="card-body targets">


              <ul class="list-unstyled h-100"
                  [dndList]="{
                    disabled: false,
                    effectAllowed: 'move',
                    allowedTypes: ['server']}"
                  [dndPlaceholder]="placeholder"
                  [dndModel]="servers">
                <li *ngFor="let server of patchGroup.servers;let i = index"
                    [dndDraggable]
                    style="cursor:pointer;">{{server.name}}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer p-1 pl-3 text-center">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Add Servers
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ng-template #noPatchGroups>
        <div class="row flex-row flex-grow flex-nowrap pb-2">
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-3 text-center pt-5 align-middle">
            <p class="font-weight-bold"> No patch groups have been created.</p>

            <p>Start by <a (click)="toggleCreateGroups()" title="Create Patch Group" class="text-primary">creating a patch group</a>. This will allow you to assign your servers to groups for the purpose of scheduling when each group is patched.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the `allowedTypes` setting, maybe the second list has trouble seeing the incoming item as a 'server' type?